# Reject parameters not in Param() statement

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a powershell script that starts with

```
Param([switch]$NoDownload, [switch]$NoUnpack, [switch]$NoExtract, [switch]$NoImport, [switch]$NoBackup)
```

and I was very happy because I thought that it would provide automatic parameter validation. Until one day I made a mistake and wrote:

```
powershell -f myscript.ps1 -NoDowload
```

(notice the lack of **n**), and it happily downloaded something I didn't want it to.

How do I tell the powershell parameter handling machinery that the only valid parameters are the ones I explicitly state in the `Param` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `CmdletBinding` attribute to the `param()` block - this makes PowerShell [treat your script/function like a cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.1) - rather than a "simple" function - and it will apply much more rigorous parameter binding validation, including throwing errors when you attempt to bind a non-existing parameter name:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [switch]$NoDownload,
  [switch]$NoUnpack,
  [switch]$NoExtract,
  [switch]$NoImport,
  [switch]$NoBackup
)
```

```
PS ~> .\myScript.ps1 -NoDowload
myScript.ps1 : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoDowload'.
At line:1 char:16
+ .\myScript.ps1 -NoDowload
+                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [myScript.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,myScript.ps1
```

---

Adding an explicit `[Parameter()]` attribute to any defined parameter will also implicitly make PowerShell treat your script/function as "advanced", even in the absence of a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute:

```
param(
  [switch]$NoDownload,
  [switch]$NoUnpack,
  [switch]$NoExtract,
  [switch]$NoImport,
  [switch]$NoBackup,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, DontShow = $true)]
  $DummyParameterThatTriggersCmdletBinding
)
```